# Geoserver stretch WMS color ramp to current view extent?

Tags: geoserver, wms, style, sld, cloud-optimized-geotiff

Is it possible to restyle a Geoserver WMS so that the color ramp is stretched across the min max values for the current map extent (bounding box)?

I want to do this for a single band DEM dataset.
This way, when zooming in to an area, the fine detail will be visible.

I have used a custom SLD_BODY parameter in WMS requests to restyle rasters in a previous project.
But this approach requires knowledge of the min and max values for the current map extent!

Perhaps the only practical option is client side styling with COG rasters?

Comment: I would try the normalize function  https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/rastersymbolizer.html#contrastenhancement.

Comment: I think for the normalize function we would need to specify the min and max of the raster data we want shown in the current bounding box, or it will just use the min and max of the entire band... Am I wrong?

Comment: If you use a simple raster style it will do this by default

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/422532/geoserver-changing-raster-color-as-scale-changes

Comment: @IanTurton I think this differs from that question because it applies to panning too (I'm assuming), not just zooming. I actually meant to ask a similar question but never got around to it.

Comment: COGs actually look pretty cool: is there a reason you want to avoid using them? Another option (which I haven't implemented yet) is to pre-color large overlapping tiles using a color key specific to that tile (easy, but nontrivial, details on request)

Comment: Try "normalize" and report your experience. Why would you need a function that works only with zooming but not with panning if that is what you meant?

Comment: @user30184 As the OP notes above, wouldn't "normalize" require providing a min and max value? I think the OP wants a solution that "automatically" uses the max and min value in a given view (which can change with every zoom and pan). An obvious solution is to compute the min/max each time, but that sounds slow

Comment: @BarryCarter thats correct

Comment: @BarryCarter yes it would be great to do client side with COGs but this is to work into an existing system and would require a big refactor.

Comment: @IanTurton I need to define a color ramp though, and apply that to the current map extent.

Comment: @user30184 Ill try normalize and report, but I think this will require a min and max value. I wonder what the most efficient way to calculate the mon and max of pixels in the current bounding box would be, maybe WPS...

Comment: @user30184 have tested and `normalize` doesnt work with a user defined color ramp

Comment: How accurate do you need this to be? For example, can the color ramp include pixels that are just off the edge of the map and thus invisible? Can we assume your users have a limited viewport size (eg, 1024x1024)?

Comment: @BarryCarter doesnt need to be accurate, its more to provide a good relative visualisation experience for local areas. But yes fine to include pixels off the edge of the map. Limited viewport size we cant really assume unfortunately, as the application is used on a variety of size monitors... On my laptop its 1290x915. What were you thinking Barry?

Comment: You could create large (2048x2048) overlapping tiles with color ramps specific to the tile and then choose which tile to show based on the user's viewport. Since the tiles overlap, you can ensure the viewer is always viewing no more than one tile, avoiding discontinuity at the edges. I'm not entirely happy with this solution, however.

Comment: @BarryCarter thanks, creative solution! But needs to work in Cesium too, 3D mode, where the viewport may include looking into the distance (our application has 2D leaflet and 3D Cesium modes so needs to do a rough job of perfroming well in both)! Might be a bit stuck here.

Comment: The Cesium requirement really complicates it now that I think about it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution would be to make a WPS request to calculate the min and max for current viewport on demand (i.e. via a button 'Stretch Color Ramp to View Extent'), and then submit a new WMS request using the min and max in a SLD_BODY parameter to restyle it.

Comment: That seems like the most obvious solution, but how fast is it in practice? You have to loop through 1M+ values and then paint 1M+ pixels after that. Or are you suggesting a halfway measure: only recompute the min and max when the user pushes a button (which I had also considered)?

Comment: Hi Barry, yes I think just when the user pushes a button. Something like 'Stretch Color Ramp'. Whats your use case out of interest? Thanks for your contribution to this issue